# nodejs set timeout on data response

Tags: node.js, file, response, mjpeg

I am trying to set a timeout in between readstream.write but I keep getting Error: write after end. How can I set a timeout in between res.write. Thank you. Here is my code.

```
app.get('/video', function (req, res) {


  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('video.mjpeg');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-  replace;boundary=ThisString'});

  readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
    res.write(chunk, 'binary');

    setTimeout(function () {
      res.write('ThisString');
    }, 200);
    console.log("Writing to client");
  });

  readStream.on("end", () => {
    readStream.destroy();
    res.end();
    console.log("End of data"); 
  });
});
```

I am trying to display the video on the client side, the problem is that the mjpeg gets read quickly thus cannot create the video. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it because the end is call before the 200ms ?

Comment: Maybe you can push them into a queue that set a minimum interval between two execution ? I don't really get the point here.

Comment: How is adding a delay to the response going to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote quickly some line of code of what I understand you need.
StackOverflow is not my favorite IDE so don't be too hard on it ^^
I don't really know the readStream but `data` event is called many time write ?
The queue is waiting the precedent chunk and its timeout are correctly finished.
Is it what you need ?

```
var kue = require('kue'),
    jobs = kue.createQueue();

app.get('/video', function (req, res) {

  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('video.mjpeg');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-  replace;boundary=ThisString'});

  jobs.process('write chunck', function (job, done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      res.write(job.chunck, 'binary');
      done && done();
    }, 200);
  });

  jobs.process('write end', function(job, done) {
    readStream.destroy();
    res.end();
    console.log("End of data");
    done & done();
  });

  readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
    jobs.create('write chunck', {
      chunk: chunk
    });
  });

  readStream.on("end", () => {
    jobs.create('write end', {});
  });
});
```

Comment: Should that be calling `jobs.create('write end')` for `readStream.on("end"` ?

Comment: Oohhh yep, my bad.